# Error when calling RokoAccount.logout()?

Tags: android

I am integrating ROKO Mobi into my Android app.

I am trying to call `RokoAccount.logout()` after I call `RokoAccount.setUser()` but I see the following error message in my client-side console log when I try to do this.

> E/btLogout: failure string: {"apiStatusCode":"AccessDenied","apiStatusMessage":"User not authorized for this action."}

Why am I receiving this?

Comment: I following document,
https://docs.roko.mobi/docs/android-integrate-sdk#section-5-identifying-the-user-recommended
but I see the following error message in my client-side console log when I try to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you're seeing this error because `RokoAccount.setUser()` executes asynchronously.

The code snippet below calls `RokoAccount.logout()` in an asynchronous fashion, give it a shot!

```
RokoAccount.setUser(this, "UserA@referrals.com", null, null, new ResponseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void success(Response response) {
        User userA = RokoAccount.getLoginUser(InfoActivity.this);
        final String userAreferralCode =  userA.referralCode;
        Log.i("userA.referralCode", "refCode = " + userAreferralCode);

        // call logout() in the asynchronous success callback of setUser()
        RokoAccount.logout(InfoActivity.this, new ResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(Response response) {
                Log.i("btLogout", "success response: " + response.body);

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(Response response) {
                Log.e("btLogout", "failure string: " + response.body);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(Response response) {

    }
});
```